# How can I get combinations with respect to value and without respect to order in python?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, all of the below should return [(2,2)] because all the tuple elements in the returned lists are the same with respect to value.

```
>>> list(combinations([2,2,2],2))
[(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)]
>>> list(combinations_with_replacement([2,2],2))
[(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)]
>>> list(combinations_with_replacement([2,2,2],2))
[(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)]
>>> list(combinations([i,i,i],2))
[(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Put the combinations in a set rather than a list: `set(combinations([2,2,2],2))`.  This only works if your items are hashable.